# iterm annoying history window

Tags: autocomplete, zsh, iterm

I have recently changed my MAC and was setting my work environment from scratch. I have noticed that now I have a feature that I've never used before. When I press up arrow up a couple of times iterm basically chooses one of the previously used commands by itself and prompts the window with all the options I have used a specific command with. For instance I recently used ls with flags -lh -ls etc. I would like to get rid off this prompt as I cannot let's say press arrow up a couple of times to look for a different command I've previously used. Screenshot below for some clarification.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9egB6.png)

Comment: This looks to me like a configuration question of iterm and therefore should be asked on [su] or on [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: That's sorted. It is a built in iterm function. To disable go to view -> Auto Command Completion